# SQL e xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, powershell

Boas pessoal, tenho este pequeno codigo em SQL:

```
DECLARE 
@StringRTF VARCHAR(MAX),
@Posh VARCHAR(8000)


SET @StringRTF = (select traduçao from artigos where Cod_Art='01010066')
select @StringRTF
SET @Posh = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $Rtb = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox; $stringRTF = \"' + (select @StringRTF) + '\"; $Rtb.Rtf = $stringRTF; $Retorno = $Rtb.Text; Write-Host($Retorno);'
select @Posh
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Posh
```

No `select @StringRTF` retorna

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fprq6\fcharset134 SimSun;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang2052\f0\fs17\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb\'b7\'eb\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb6346\'b8\'f6\'ba\'ec\'b5\'c4\'b9\'f0\'bb\'a8\lang2070\f1   \par }

No `select @Posh` retorna

> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $Rtb = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox; $stringRTF = \"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fprq6\fcharset134 SimSun;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang2052\f0\fs17\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb\'b7\'eb\'b7\'f2\'c8\'cb6346\'b8\'f6\'ba\'ec\'b5\'c4\'b9\'f0\'bb\'a8\lang2070\f1   \par }\"; $Rtb.Rtf = $stringRTF; $Retorno = $Rtb.Text; Write-Host($Retorno);

Se eu copiar o que retorna no `@Posh` e o por no cmd, ele faz o que é pedido

> 夫人冯夫人6346个红的桂花

mas em SQL da-me sempre erro e já não estou a conseguir perceber o porque.

O erro que da em SQL é :

> The string is missing the terminator: ".
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx     ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

O que é que poderá estar mal no `SET @Posh`?!